# Symfony4 + jwt-auth rescipe always return {"code":401,"message":"Bad credentials"}

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle

I've a Symfony4 installation with few common bundles installed with Flex

- make
- jwt-auth
- annotation
- behat
- phpunit
- server

I've this routing file:

```
api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

I've this configuration:

```
security:

    encoders:
        App\Security\User: plaintext

    providers:
        app.provider:
            id: App\Security\UserProvider

    firewalls:

        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: app.provider
            form_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            provider: app.provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

and this user:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;

class User implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface
{
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $salt;
    private $roles;

    public function __construct($username, $password, $salt, array $roles)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->salt = $salt;
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->password !== $user->getPassword()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->salt !== $user->getSalt()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->username !== $user->getUsername()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

and finally this user provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Security\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;

class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $username = 'senso';
        $password = 'rario';
        $salt     = 'sale';
        $roles    = ['ROLE_ADMIN'];

        return new User($username, $password, $salt, $roles);

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
            sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
        );
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user))
            );
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return User::class === $class;
    }
}
```

When I run

> curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/login_check -d _username=senso -d _password=rario
>   {"code":401,"message":"Bad credentials"}

I always get

> {"code":401,"message":"Bad credentials"}

My questions are:

- how to fix this?
- why UserProvider::loadUserByUsername() was never called?

Comment: Can you post the correct `curl` that you tried? I want to check if: the url is the correct one ( and not `http://localhost:800ogin_check` as posted), and the password chosed is `rario`, not `test`.

Comment: Can you add the `provider: app.provider` under the `login` firewall?

Comment: done, stil not work

Comment: I'm assuming that you registered `/api/login_check` in your router configuration, can you confirm?

Comment: yes. I've ypdated question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167961/discussion-between-federkun-and-sensorario).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `PlaintextPasswordEncoder` and providing a `salt` to your `User` class, then your `User`'s `getPassword` method should return `plain_password{salt}`.

In this case,

```
$username = 'senso';
$password = 'rario{sale}';
$salt     = 'sale';
$roles    = ['ROLE_ADMIN'];

return new User($username, $password, $salt, $roles);
```

or

```
$username = 'senso';
$password = 'rario';
$salt     = '';
$roles    = ['ROLE_ADMIN'];

return new User($username, $password, $salt, $roles);
```

will be fine to use.